# Will UPDATE be called if I "change" a column value to what it already is?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-update, sqldataadapter, sqlcommandbuilder

I am trying to figure out if I need additional logic to avoid a useless call to my SQL db, or if `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` will do the right thing.  If I have this code:

```
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
sqlconn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectString, sqlconn);
SqlDataTable table = new SqlDataTable();
da.Fill(table);
new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
table.Rows[0][columnName] = 5; // Existing value is already 5
da.Update(table);
```

Will `.Update()` still call SQL's `UPDATE` for that row, or will it not, because no values for the row really changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will call the update statement in SQL, because changing a value in `DataSet` and setting it to same again, **will modify** the `RowState` property.

[DataAdapter.Update - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx)

> When an application calls the Update method, the **DataAdapter
>   examines the RowState property**, and executes the required INSERT,
>   UPDATE, or DELETE statements iteratively for each row, based on the
>   order of the indexes configured in the DataSet.

You can also confirm it using SQL Profiler.